# Supported versions of Java - Question scope

Tags: discussion

Many of us have struggled with different versions of JAVA causing problems with Tridion and I recognise that the [What is the newest version of Java 6 supported on Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/what-is-the-newest-version-of-java-6-supported-on-tridion-2011-sp1-hr1) question is very relevant and the answers will be very useful.

However, this seems like a very limited scope (possibly a good thing).  Would the question be better as **What versions of Java are supported and proven to work for Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1?**.  This would encourage answers listing all versions to be given- not just giving the latest version.

I guess someone could list all of the supported and proven versions in their answer, but I wonder if the question could be made more useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the power to edit the question - it looks like people are giving those sorts of answers anyway but you're free to edit the question and leave a comment explaining your edits. I'd have said you have a good point.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  I didn't want to edit the question as it may affect the readability of some of the answers given and upset the asker.  I wondered about leaving a comment suggesting that the user updates the question themselves.

Comment: I decided that sufficient time has passed for DanielGLB to get the answer that he sought.  I have re-titled and reworded the question to be more useful to future visitors to the site.

Comment: Jonathan, you also have the power to edit the other answers to tweak them to match any edits to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with your points, but the Question poster need to think from that perspective along with just getting his query resolve.

Regardless, I have updated my answer to inclined it in the direction you are looking for :)

Comment: Thanks Pankaj - I have updated the question and your answer should be very useful to future visitors.